# Unique Characters

Tags: java, arraylist, unique

I am working on a project for my class. We have to find the number of unique hashtags in a tweet that is input into Java. I am relatively new to coding, so I am stuck with how to find out the unique hashtags. So far, I only have the scanner.

```
package edu.bsu.cs121.jmgibson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HashTag {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<String> hashtag = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner tweet = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        hashtag.add(tweet.next());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What is your question

Comment: I am stuck on how to find the unique inputs. How would I go about finding them. Would I use a for loop (thats how I believe to find them, but could be wrong). And if so, how do I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the usage of a Scanner:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

You will firstly want to identify how to create the needed delimiter. There is an example in the link, however you will be looking for a substring that begins with # and ends with whitespace. Since this is a homework assignment an exact answer cannot be given - however, the custom delimiter will get you where you need to be.

Answer (score -1):

In general, to find unique words in a string input, you could add each word to a hashtable (`HashMap` in java?), checking if it already exists or not.

Then when you iterate through the hash table afterwards, those are your unique hashtags.

You'll need to modify this solution to only add the hashtags to the hash table/map of course.